# Do cyclists in France have priority when crossing a road?

Tags: legal, france, automobiles, bicycles, road-signs

Specifically when the road they are crossing has bicycle signs on it, such as this crossing in Versailles:

[image]

The road going horizontally (left-right) on the picture is a normal road (for cars) and the one vertical (with the people walking) is a bike path (yes, despite people walking on it - it is better than the parallel one for pedestrians, on the left, on the other side of the green band).

**While this picture depicts a specific crossing, the question is general for crossing of road/bike roads where there are bicycle markings (bike logos) on the crossing.**

Comment: That's a warning for pedestrians that bikes are crossing. Pedestrians typically need to give priority when they cross a street (unless it's a zebra crossing).

Comment: In particular it seems to be a warning that the crossing path have cyclists going in both direction. (Perhaps some pedestrians might reflexively only look left when stepping out, expecting that the traffic in the other direction is on the lane we see in the distance).

Comment: @Aganju: I updated my question with some details, the horizontal road is for cars, the vertical one for bikes)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I updated my question with some details, the horizontal road is for cars, the vertical one for bikes)

Comment: I spent a week bicycling in France this summer and was also mostly confused by the signage and road markings. I have for example no idea what these creative white and blue road markings at a crossing in Tours are supposed to mean. There is no dedicated bicycle path nearby: https://www.google.de/maps/@47.3913983,0.6976579,3a,64.2y,349h,83.47t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s1Ght5oauMf9XsI-ACBXaqA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: the ones in front of the traffic lights mean that there is a "sas" - a place where bikes await for the green light and cars cannot stop there. The idea is that the start of the bikes will be safer as cars will see them in front (and not to the right or left where they can miss them). The ones on the right and left mean (I believe) that the pavement is shared between pedestrians and cyclists.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo bicycle markings next to pedestrian crossings without light controls are confusing in UK too. Although our Highway Code advises that a bicycle should be "walked" across, some councils seem to be advising them as a cycling route. It is very dangerous: bicycles can appear too quickly for a driver to react properly.

Comment: @WoJ That makes sense, but not being familiar with the road markings and each city seemingly creating their own creative art work with bicycle pictograms in different colours on the streets, it was not exactly obvious ;-) My immediate guess at the white markings before the traffic lights was rather that *that* is the intended bicycle lane for crossing traffic from right and left.

Comment: @Aganju, in France, pedestrians also have priority when there are no zebra crossings within 50 meters.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: sure, the fact that many of the marking (notably for cyclists) are so disparate between countries is a pain.

Comment: @jcaron: it is much more complicated than that. Pederstrians have **always** priority, even if they are in their wrong (including crossing at their red light!). This is a real mess, the law is [R415-11](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000023095972&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006074228) and  https://www.legipermis.com/blog/2015/05/18/pieton-qui-traverse-au-rouge-est-il-dans-son-droit/ (fr) gives a good general explanation (though it i sstill confusing)

Comment: @WoJ They have priority if they started crossing the road in an acceptable way ("piéton s'engageant régulièrement dans la traversée d'une chaussée..."), or plan to do so. Article R412-37 states that they should cross on a zebra crossing if there's one within 50 meters (there are other conditions as well). So if they do cross outside of a zebra crossing when there's one, they do not have *priority*. That doesn't mean cars should run them over of course, and if they do, they will be responsible for corporal damages even if they did have priority.

Comment: @jcaron: you are right. I did not read *régulièrement engagé* clearly enough (it is explained e.g. [here](https://www.permis-apoints.com/infraction-refus-de-priorite-a-un-pieton.html)). I stand corrected. There is also [a good document by the CERTU](http://www.securite-routiere.gouv.fr/content/download/3182/28014/version/1/file/Fiche2_decret_12112010_TraversePieton_cle298117.pdf)  explaining this in details with showcases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Only pedestrians have priority in France when crossing a road. (French Highway Code: [R415-11](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000023095972&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006074228) [fr]).

Bike logos are intended to raise attention to other drivers.

Comment: Thanks. Also [R415-14](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006842254&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006074228&dateTexte=20180910&oldAction=rechCodeArticle&fastReqId=148721270&nbResultRech=1) mentions that the bike path is to be treated as a road, so all priority measures apply.

Comment: but this is rather not bike path as it's not properly indicated; this is rather just paved road which happened someone painted bikes on crossing the real road; bike path needs proper vertical signs to be bike path

Answer (score -1):

France has best traffic signs for vehicles, cyclists, pedestrians. Usually when there is no traffic sign then the general rule is slower moving object has priority. So pedestrians always have priority over cyclists, and cyclists over vehicles...BUT only when there is no traffic sign yet installed at a location or in less crowded areas like rural roads.
In your picture the path going up the pic is only for pedestrians as the sign partially hidden behind tree shows NO CYCLISTS.
However, in France due to narrow streets and congested traffic, usually drivers ignore pedestrians standing by on sidewalk to cross street even on marked crosswalks and do not stop at all and more amazing is while pedestrians have priority they hesitate for a long period avoiding stepping on marked crosswalk to cross. Drivers explain their action: if I stop suddenly the car behind me hit my car and I hit the pedestrian so it is safe to pass until it is clear for pedestrian to cross!!! What a stupid reasoning. In Canada drivers stop way back the marked crossing even when 1 or 2 pedestrians standing on sidewalk at marked crosswalks but not intend to cross the street!

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. 1. the legal article provided in mouviciel's answer (+ the one in my comment) show that there is nothing special about cyclists and their priority. 2. the path going up the pic is for bicycles, not pedestrians. The one for pedestrians is on the left (this is Avenue de Paris in Versailles if you are curious). 3. France is big and there are places with narrow roads and places with wide roads; places with congested traffic and places without any. 4. I have never heard of your explanation about not stopping at zebras, do you have any source for that?